# Basic Mysql select with Where clause not working. Same query in CLI works

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, mysql-python

I want to do a select with mysql connector. I have this:

```
    subcategory = "Test"
    c = mydb.cursor()
    sql = "SELECT id FROM Department WHERE subcategory='%s'"
    c.execute(sql, subcategory)
    res = c.fetchone()
    print(res)
```

Output:

```
None
```

But it always returns None.
If I run that same select from mysql cli, it works fine:

```
SELECT id FROM Department WHERE subcategory='Test'
```

Output:

```
1
```

Why wouldn't it work?
Thanks!

Comment: remove the single quotes arround `%s`

Comment: True, those quotes shouldn't be there, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html `execute` expects `params` (ie. second parameter) to be a tuple, not a string. Try using:

```
c.execute(sql, (subcategory,))
```